# How to refer to cell within another worksheet to allow for movement of data based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

In my work there are user metrics provided in .CSV form to be analysed.

I built an Excel sheet to do this for my team. The goal is to send data for each user (name is in column 4) to its own separately named sheet within the workbook. I use a separate macro for each user.

```vb
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet() 
DATA DUMP.Activate 
DATA DUMP.Cells.Select 
For Each myCell In Selection.Columns(4).Cells 
If myCell.Value = "User Name" 
Then myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("User Name").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2) 
End If 
Next 
End Sub
```

I have taken oversight over another team and I don't want to keep adding a macro for every user. Instead I added a pivot table to return the names of all users in the raw data and was hoping to refer to this list rather than having to manually rewrite everything for each team.
As a compromise it would be fine to send the data to a generically named sheet (i.e., "User 1", "User 2" and so forth) or some such other name.

Something like this

```vb
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet() 
DATA DUMP.Activate 

DATA DUMP.Cells.Select
For Each myCell In Selection.Columns(4).Cells
If myCell.Value = "REFERENCE TO CELL A2 IN A DIFFERENT WORKSHEET"
Then myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("USER 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).
End(3)(2)
End If 
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Plenty of previous posts on this topic:  https://www.google.com/search?q=split+worksheet+by+column+value+vba+site+stackoverflow.com

Comment: I have read these and used them to assist in creating the original macro, these do not assist with what I am trying to do which is refer to the variable with a cell reference rather than coding it into the macro.

These also assume the new worksheets need to be created but in this scenario the data just needs to be moved to worksheets with a generic name based on the user ID that is being pulled from a pivot table in a separate worksheet. For reference, there are about 30 macros similar to this and each currently has a hardcoded user name and sheet name to send to, as mentioned, I am novice.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```vb
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet() 
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    For Each c in DATA DUMP.UsedRange.Columns(4).Cells
        c.Entirerow.Copy _
           Worksheets(c.Value).cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: This code would move cells where I want them to go which I can already do with my sample code, I must be misreading the code as I can't see where you are referring to the pivot table to calculate whether a row should or should not be moved. 'Worksheets(c.Value)' is the sheet to move to and 'rows.count' is just to debnote how many rows to move but the idea is the value of column 4 should be used to decide whether or not to move the cells. To be clear, the first sample code is what I use currently and it works. I just want to change how I am referencing the user ID from hardcoded to cell ref

Comment: Your stated aim is to "send data for each user" to a sheet named for the user.  I'm not sure what you mean by "whether a row should or should not be moved" - are all rows not being moved?  There's nothing in your post about only some rows being moved.

Comment: Tims code should work without the need for a pivot providing there is a sheet for each name in column 4.  The `For Each c` line looks at each value in column 4.  `c.EntireRow.Copy` copies that entire row.  `Worksheets(c.value)` paste it to a the last row of a sheet with the same name as the value in column 4.